# Rewriting $2x^2-12x+11$ by completing the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to rewrite $2x^2-12x+11$ in square form. According to my book, the answer is $2(x-3)^2-7$. However, I get $2(x-3)^2+2$ for some reason.

**My Steps:**

$2x^2-12x+11$

$2x^2-12x=-11$

$2(x^2-6x)=-11$

$2(x^2-6x+9)=-11+9$

$2(x - 3)^2=-2$

$2(x-3)^2+2$

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: In the fourth line, you have to add $18$ to the right member and not $9$.

Comment: The line where you are adding 9 to both sides is wrong. Note on the left side you actually added 18.

Comment: I see! thanks, this helps!

Comment: Note that you can verify your constant coefficient by setting $x=3$ in the original equation $18-36+11=-7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, in the fourth line, you have to add 18 to the right member and not 9.

$2x^2-12x+11=0$

$2x^2-12x=-11$

$2(x^2-6x)=-11$

$2(x^2-6x+9)=-11+18$

$2(x - 3)^2=7$

$2(x-3)^2-7=0$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to see how this all works is to note that completing the square **doesn't** change the value of the expression. What you are essentially doing is adding a cleverly-written $0$ to it so that it becomes easier to work with.

Observe, $$\begin{align}2x^2-12x+11 & = 2x^2 - 12x \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad +11 \tag{Leave space}\\ &= 2[x^2 - 6x]\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\; +11 \tag{Factor}\\&= 2[x^2 - 6x +\underbrace{\left({-6\over2}\right)^2 - \left({-6\over2}\right)^2}_\text{cleverly-written zero}] + 11 \\ &= 2[\underbrace{x^2 - 6x + 9}_{(x-3)^2} - 9] + 11\\ &= 2[(x-3)^2 - 9] + 11\\ &= 2(x-3)^2 - 18 + 11\\ &= 2(x-3)^2 - 7.\end{align}$$